# Turning off Teamviewer's view (desktop feed)

Tags: teamviewer

Consider this scenario: I'm connected to another PC via Teamviewer, and I am transferring files, using VOIP etc. But I want to turn off the remote desktop viewing feature (to stop seeing the other guy's desktop), to conserve bandwidth. (because we both have very large screens)

Is this possible?

I guess you could use View->Select Single Window, and choose a very small window. But can you just turn off the View completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. But consider this: TeamViewer doesn't send data if it doesn't have to.  Open `Extra -> Connection Info` and you will see the traffic statistics for the session (obviously *before* you start transferring your files).  If you sit idly with a black background and nothing happening, it's only going to send about 1kB/s if it has no reason to redraw areas of the screen.  If that amount is going to hinder your transfer rate I think there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Okay. I never checked the idle bandwidth usage... I guess it's all right then.